# How can I do a ternary operator inside a map with the mapping for the true condition but without the mapping for the false

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator

I'm trying to return a table with data mapped from an api. When a condition is true I want the data to be mapped and returned but when it's false I want a message to be returned.
Here's my code :

```
{ability?.pokemon?.map((ap) => 
  ap.is_hidden === false ? (
    <tr key={ap.pokemon.name} className='ability_container_table_body_row'>
      (multiple td tag)
    </tr>
  ) : (
    <tr>
      <td>No pokémon has this ability</td>
    </tr>
  )
)}
```

The problem is that I need to map the ability.pokemon because otherwise it will only return the data for the first object of the array.
The above code is returning multiple message (one for every pokemon that doesn' check the condition) and I want it to be rendered only once.

Edit : I'm using React JS

Comment: If I understand this correctly and you are trying to check if this condition is true for any of the mapped values, why not use something like [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)? This will give you an indication of whether or not the condition is true and then you can proceed as you wish.

Comment: @tomleb3 I've never used this function. Can you tell me where I should put it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let items = []
const allHidden = ability?.pokemon?.every(ap => ap.is_hidden)
if (allHidden) {
  // No pokemon has this ability
  items = <tr><td>No pokemon has this ability</td><tr>
} else {
 // ... map all visible ones here
 items = ability?.pokemon?.map(ap => !ap.is_hidden && (
    <tr key={ap.pokemon.name} className='ability_container_table_body_row'>
      (multiple td tag)
    </tr>
  ))}
}
return <table>{items}</table> // return or assign items: just an example
```

Check if every pokemon is hidden. If true, then display your "No pokemon", if not, map the visible ones.

The every method checks if all mapped matches the condition.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

https://jsfiddle.net/04fz683g/1/

Comment: Where do I put that : before the map or inside it ?

Comment: Depending on how you have your code structured (if you want a better answer, provide more code), my answer would completely change how you handle your code. This will not go inside the map. In the else is where you map the items that are not hidden. Then you can output/return either the "no pokemon" or the mapped items

Comment: Thx I just solved the problem :)